# why my windows receive en_setfocus 12 times

Tags: mfc, windows-messages

I want to be notified when user click the password text field.
[image]
But when I do click the password text field, the following function is called more than once:

```
void CUserDlg::OnSetfocusPasswordEdit()
 {
 // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    cout << "focus on password text field";
 }
```

Why does this happen ?
I also tried :

```
LRESULT CFakeUserDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

// TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
switch (message)
{
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDC_PASSWORD_EDIT:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS)
        {
            cout << "";
            
        }
        cout << "";
        break;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

This also happens many times when I click the text field only once.

I just tried to spy++, but it shows that spy++ caputure edit control messages, but `EN_SETFOCUS` is not message, it is edit control notification.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question.  What have you tried in order to debug it?  Have you used Spy++ to check the message stream and see if there are actually multiple WM_SETFOCUS messages happening or maybe you've got a bug somewhere else that makes the code think it's happening multiple times.

Comment: Not WM_SETFOCUS

Comment: Right, sorry.  EN_SETFOCUS notifications, which you could also check with Spy++.

Comment: I just tried to spy++, but it shows that spy++ caputure edit control messages, but EN_SETFOCUS is not message, it is edit control notification.

Comment: I thought Spy++ had a way to watch for particular notifications as well, but I can't find that setting now, so maybe I'm misremembering.  What else have you tried to debug this?

Comment: I tried to use the same function(OnSetfocusPasswordEdit) for a fully functional application, it also has the same problem. So I guess it is not because "maybe you've got a bug somewhere else that makes the code think it's happening multiple times.", it must related to the WindowProc function, maybe I didn't use correct judgment condition .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got answer by myself.
**Edit control does keep sending EN_SETFOCUS when it gets the focus.**